# How to make the matplotlib subscript and special characters?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a subscript for the axis label of my plot plotted using matplotlib. I have the following script snapshot:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
plt.ylabel(r'$A^{2}$')
```

I have 2 questions:

1. In the plot, the subscript "2" seems occupying a whole word length in stead of half, which make the plot a little bit weird. How to make the subscript smaller (both in size and the length span)?
2. How to display "angstroms" (the length unit of 10^-10m) instead of A?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. What version of matplotlib are you using? In my version the superscript seems fine (to me). 
   Im using python 2.6.5 and matplotlib 1.1.0
2. Use \AA for angstram --> plt.ylabel("$\AA$"). 
   The circle is a bit small, though.

Answer (score 2):

If it's available to you, try using TeX to render your text.

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex=True)

#the rest of your plotting code here
```

This should make your fonts and text look a whole lot better.

For more details on matplotlib's TeX rendering capabilities, look here: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/usetex.html